# \chaptermark undefined error in classicthesis.sty when I (attempt to) redefine \spacedlowsmallcaps

Tags: fonts, macros, environments, fontspec, classicthesis

My MWE does not compile and the error is: `! LaTeX Error: \chaptermark undefined.`  I have debugged to the extent that I know the error is the interaction between `classicthesis` and my `\SC` command somehow interacting with `\spacedlowsmallcaps` -- which is why I am attempting to re-define the `\spacedlowsmallcaps` control sequence.

Basically I am trying to wrest control of smallcaps from `classicthesis`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}

\newfontfamily{\SCaps}{Alegreya SC}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\SC}{\SCaps}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\renewcommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\DeclareRobustCommand{\SC{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `classicthesis` is the source of basically any problem in this universe ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And that is why engineers invented duct tape (which is like the Star Wars' "force")... it has a light side, it has a dark side, and it binds the universe together.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that aspect of this problem.

Comment: `scrartcl` does not define `\chapter`. If you want to use this class you have to set option `nochapters` for `classicthesis`. Or you switch to `scrreprt` or `scrbook`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: `classicthesis` is even worse than the Dark side ;-)

Comment: Thanks @esdd now it compiles, but absolutely refuses to use the `Alegreya SC` font, either with the redefined `\spacedlowsmallcaps` or with `\SC` Anybody have a handle on why? I guess I might need to post a separate question.

Comment: By the way, do people use `classicthesis` because it gives better results in some way; given the acknowledged source of problems it causes.

Comment: @AFeldman It surely gives better results, typographically speaking (standard classes are just OK, KOMA-script classes, if I may say, look really ugly), and sure there's a price to pay for using it. You'll see (two!) people complaining about it here, saying it should never be used, and I'm thinking they probably have some personal issues with it. The package is far from perfect, sure, still you don't see better options being developed. Specifically, I'd really like to see `\spacedlowsmallcaps` being defined so that it acts as a font switch (i.e. like `\scshape `, not `\MakeLowercase{}`)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Thanks much for the explanation, and for your below remark on the need for a robust command also.

Comment: There is more than just two of us ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @Johannes_B I like the way things look with `classicthesis` but I am no expert on typographical things.  I do notice that it takes forever to compile.

Comment: @AFeldman The typography is one thing, the implementation another. For example, `classicthesis` is designed to work with a KOMA class, but does no testing if it is used. No problem though, it loads needed packages. But it does *not* set the options that are needed for a sane type block. Use the package with `book` or something and use `\Blinddocument` (from `blindtext`) and you will notice, something is off. `classicthesis` also uses `scrpage` which is now deprecated for i think two years. And it uses `titlesec` which raises quite some erros with KOMA.  `classicthesis` needs an update, now.

Comment: You're right, @Johannes_B, about headinclude and footinclude - they should be always there. You're not right about scrpage, classicthesis has switched to scrlayer-scrpage. Not sure if there's an easy solution for titlesec+koma, seems that koma will relax it's requirements now. Is there a better way of doing what titlesec does, but remaining compatible with classes other than koma? Sure, one could do it from scratch, and still  run into same problems. http://www.komascript.de/titlesec

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Uses `scrlayer-scrpage` but still with the old compatibility commands of `scrpage2`. `classicthesis` should be a class file, not a package. That way, no testing would be needed on the class used. You would need to test for KOMA, which has its own `\DeclareSectionCommand`, standard classes *and* `memoir` and provide appropriate things for all.

Comment: Templates are a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you get an error: if you want to use `scrartcl` you have to call

```
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
```

However your redefinition of `\spacedlowsmallcaps` makes no sense:

```
\renewcommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\SC{#1}}
```

is probably what you want.

---

There is no need to do tricks, though.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\setmainfont{Alegreya}[
  SmallCapsFont=* SC,
]

\begin{document}

Hello World

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to rely on `soul` for letter spacing when using XeLaTeX, add this code before `\begin{document}`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{{%
  \normalfont\scshape
  \addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=10}%
  \MakeLowercase{#1}%
}}
```

Comment: I had used `\DeclareRobustCommand` because the definition of `\spacedlowsmallcaps` contained that command.  Why did inclusion of `\DeclareRobustCommand`  prevent the font from changing?  And thanks for answering both the question asked and the comment question.

Comment: @AFeldman Your usage of `\DeclareRobustCommand` is wrong to begin with; it's much similar to `\newcommand`: does it make sense there?

Comment: When you put it that way it seems obvious.  So given that `\spacedlowsmallcaps` was defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand` I should probably use it for my redefinition.

Comment: @AFeldman Currently, \spacedlowsmallcaps is in a few cases being written to the .toc file, that's why, I think, it's been defined as robust.  The way you used `\DeclareRobustCommand` is wrong: that command is equivalent to `\newcommand`, as egreg pointed out, not just something that makes its argument robust. Note that with this redefinition your titles won't be either spaced or low, just regular smallcaps.

Comment: The reason for the question is that I wanted to use Alegreya throughout, and without the redefinition, that did not seem to be possible as `\spacedlowsmallcaps` stopped working (no smallcaps) the moment I changed the font.

Comment: @AFeldman I added the real way to cope with the problem, based on the new information you gave.

Comment: Check if `pdfspacing` option is in the call to classicthesis. Soul package letterspacing tends to break more often.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, much better to use that than my idea.

Comment: Oh, nevermind... You're using XeLaTeX, classicthesis will switch to `soul` anyway.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I added a way to avoid `soul`.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip thanks for your comments, I usually use lualatex.  I'll keep in mind your warning regarding `soul`.