# Align to left all the equations

Tags: equations, align

There is someone who knows how to make all the eqautions in a file strating from the same point?
I would like to obation something like the pic linked[image]

My header is this one (i know it's a very old set up)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\linespread{1.1}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bold {#1} }
\newcommand{\aver}[1]{\left\langle {#1} \right\rangle}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You will find out that what you want is pretty useless in any regular document. It just disturbs the reading.

Comment: You seem to be still using that old template. It isn't good. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports and the very new https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-to-use-complex-templates

Comment: just add the `fleqn` option on `\documentclass` then set `\mathindent` to the point that you want them to start.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right. I was writing a paper for my professor, and we wanted to deliver it as a report for my thesis. Unfortunately my university rejected that format and now i have to re-write all my work with another format provided by the univerisity. Thanks another time for your suggest. I will surely take it in consideration for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `fleqn` option on `\documentclass` then set `\mathindent` to the point that you want them to start.