# Why does 1-column framed text on 2-column template mess up typesetting?

Tags: formatting, two-column, typography, mdframed, journal

I am trying to use the Royal Society of Chemistry's latex [article template](http://www.rsc.org/globalassets/05-journals-books-databases/journal-authors-reviewers/author-templates/rsc-articletemplate.zip) for formatting my manuscript.

With the given template,everything works fine. However,when I try to include a (highly desirable) customised single-column content immediately after the abstract (formatted using the `mdframed` package),the typesetting of all subsequent sections goes haywire. I am attaching the typeset messy PDF here. The content that I am trying to insert is titled 'Broader Context'.[image: messed up rsc image]

Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated.I do not wish to begin a new page for the broader context. I simply want to place the broader context frame box immediately after the abstract, and then continue onto introduction section without any pagebreak anywhere.

Here is my source code. I am sorry that it is a bit too long (most content comes from the journal's template itself). The exact code will not compile unless the figures from the journal's template are downloaded and extracted. However, I am just looking for a proof-of-concept method which will work in an example simpler document which you may choose to use.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.785cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font={stretch=1.125,small,sf},labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%Please don't disable any packages in the preamble, as this may cause the template to display incorrectly.%%%


\usepackage{epstopdf}%This line makes .eps figures into .pdf - please comment out if not required.
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{broader_background}{RGB}{230,226,214}
\newmdenv[linecolor=white,frametitle=Broader Context]{broadercontextbox}

\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{222,217,201}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{

    %%%HEADER%%%
    \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=18.5cm]{head_foot/header_bar}}
    \fancyhead[L]{\hspace{0cm}\vspace{1.5cm}\includegraphics[height=30pt]{head_foot/journal_name}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\hspace{0cm}\vspace{1.7cm}\includegraphics[height=55pt]{head_foot/RSC_LOGO_CMYK}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%%%END OF HEADER%%%

%%%PAGE SETUP - Please do not change any commands within this section%%%
\makeFNbottom
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{15pt}{17}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12pt}{14}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{10pt}{12}}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize{7pt}{10}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{1pt}%
\color{cream}\hrule width 3.5in height 0.4pt \color{black}\vspace*{5pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]%
{\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\@thefnmark\,}#1}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\small{Fig.}~}
\sectionfont{\sffamily\Large}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsubsectionfont{\bf}
\setstretch{1.125} %In particular, please do not alter this line.
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.25cm}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{4pt}{4pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15pt}{1pt}
%%%END OF PAGE SETUP%%%

%%%FOOTER%%%
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\vspace{-7.1pt}\includegraphics[height=9pt]{head_foot/LF}}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\vspace{-7.1pt}\hspace{13.2cm}\includegraphics{head_foot/RF}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{\vspace{-7.2pt}\hspace{-14.2cm}\includegraphics{head_foot/RF}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footnotesize{\sffamily{1--\pageref{LastPage} ~\textbar  \hspace{2pt}\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\footnotesize{\sffamily{\thepage~\textbar\hspace{3.45cm} 1--\pageref{LastPage}}}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6.5mm}
\setlength\bibsep{1pt}
%%%END OF FOOTER%%%

%%%FIGURE SETUP - please do not change any commands within this section%%%
\makeatletter
\newlength{\figrulesep}
\setlength{\figrulesep}{0.5\textfloatsep}

\newcommand{\topfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}%
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\newcommand{\botfigrule}{\vspace*{-2pt}%
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\newcommand{\dblfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}%
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\makeatother
%%%END OF FIGURE SETUP%%%

%%%TITLE, AUTHORS AND ABSTRACT%%%
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{m{4.5cm} p{13.5cm} }

        \includegraphics{head_foot/DOI} & \noindent\LARGE{\textbf{This is the title$^\dag$}} \\%Article title goes here instead of the text "This is the title"
        \vspace{0.3cm} & \vspace{0.3cm} \\

                       & \noindent\large{Full Name,$^{\ast}$\textit{$^{a}$} Full Name,\textit{$^{b\ddag}$} and Full Name\textit{$^{a}$}} \\%Author names go here instead of "Full name", etc.

        \includegraphics{head_foot/dates} & \noindent\normalsize
        {
            augue. Donec eros nisi, imperdiet quis, volutpat ac, sollicitudin sed, arcu. Aenean vel mauris.
            Mauris tincidunt.  Nullam euismod odio at  velit. Praesent elit purus,  porttitor id, facilisis
            in, consequat ut, libero. Morbi imperdiet,  magna quis ullamcorper malesuada, mi massa pharetra
            lectus, a pellentesque urna  urna id turpis. Nam posuere lectus vitae  nibh. Etiam tortor orci,
            sagittis malesuada, rhoncus quis, hendrerit eget, libero. Quisque commodo nulla at nunc. Mauris
            consequat, enim vitae  venenatis sollicitudin, dolor orci bibendum enim,  a sagittis nulla nunc
            quis elit. Phasellus augue. Nunc suscipit, magna.


        } \\

    \end{tabular}

\end{@twocolumnfalse} \vspace{0.6cm}

]
%%%END OF TITLE, AUTHORS AND ABSTRACT%%%
\vspace{-20mm}
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace{1mm}
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{p{18cm}}
        \begin{broadercontextbox}[backgroundcolor=broader_background]
            % lorem{{{ Non suscipit gravida, velit enim aliquam quam, nec condimentum orci augue vel magna.
            Nulla facilisi. Donec ipsum  enim, congue in, tempus id, pulvinar sagittis,  leo. Donec et elit
            in nunc blandit  auctor. Nulla congue urna quis  lorem. Nam rhoncus pede sed  nunc. Etiam vitae
            quam. Fusce feugiat pede vel quam. In et augue.

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

            Phasellus mollis dictum  nulla. Integer vitae neque vitae eros  fringilla rutrum. Vestibulum in
            pede adipiscing  mi dapibus  condimentum. Etiam  felis risus,  condimentum in,  malesuada eget,
            pretium ut,  sapien. Suspendisse placerat  lectus venenatis  lorem. Sed accumsan  aliquam enim.
            Etiam hendrerit, metus eu semper. % lorem}}}


        \end{broadercontextbox}
    \end{tabular}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}

%%%FONT SETUP - please do not change any commands within this section
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{bch}\normalfont\upshape
\rmfamily
\section*{}
\vspace{-1cm}


%%%FOOTNOTES%%%

\footnotetext{\textit{$^{a}$~Address, Address, Town, Country. Fax: XX XXXX XXXX; Tel: XX XXXX XXXX; E-mail: xxxx@aaa.bbb.ccc}}
\footnotetext{\textit{$^{b}$~Address, Address, Town, Country. }}

%Please use \dag to cite the ESI in the main text of the article.
%If you article does not have ESI please remove the the \dag symbol from the title and the footnotetext below.
\footnotetext{\dag~Electronic Supplementary Information (ESI) available: [details of any supplementary information available should be included here]. See DOI: 10.1039/b000000x/}
%additional addresses can be cited as above using the lower-case letters, c, d, e... If all authors are from the same address, no letter is required

\footnotetext{\ddag~Additional footnotes to the title and authors can be included \textit{e.g.}\ `Present address:' or `These authors contributed equally to this work' as above using the symbols: \ddag, \textsection, and \P. Please place the appropriate symbol next to the author's name and include a \texttt{\textbackslash footnotetext} entry in the the correct place in the list.}


%%%END OF FOOTNOTES%%%

%%%MAIN TEXT%%%%
The main text of the article\cite{Mena2000} should appear here.

\section{Introduction}
% lorem{{{  Lobortis faucibus  mi. Aenean vitae  risus ut arcu  malesuada ornare.  Maecenas nec
erat. Sed rhoncus, elit laoreet sagittis luctus,  nulla leo faucibus lectus, vitae accumsan est
diam id felis. Nunc dui pede, vestibulum eu, elementum et, gravida quis, sapien. Donec blandit.
Donec  sed magna.  Curabitur a  risus. Nullam  nibh libero,  sagittis vel,  hendrerit accumsan,
pulvinar consequat, tellus. Donec varius dictum  nisl. Vestibulum suscipit enim ac nulla. Proin
tincidunt. Proin sagittis. Curabitur auctor metus  non mauris. Nunc condimentum nisl non augue.
Donec leo urna, dignissim vitae, porttitor ut, iaculis sit amet, sem.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per. % lorem}}}






\subsection{Tables}
Tables typeset in RSC house style do not include vertical lines. Table footnote symbols are lower-case italic letters and are typeset at the bottom of the table. Table captions do not end in a full point.\cite{Arduengo1992,Eisenstein2005}


\begin{table}[h]
    \small
    \caption{\ An example of a caption to accompany a table}
    \label{tbl:example}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.48\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
        \hline
        Header one (units) & Header two & Header three \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

Adding notes to tables can be complicated.  Perhaps the easiest method is to generate these manually.\footnote[4]{Footnotes should appear here. These might include comments relevant to but not central to the matter under discussion, limited experimental and spectral data, and crystallographic data.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is way to long, also it doesn't compile due to the missing graphics.

But it should work if you put your box also in the optional argument of \twocolumn like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{broader_background}{RGB}{230,226,214}
\newmdenv[linecolor=white,frametitle=Broader Context]{broadercontextbox}


\begin{document}

\twocolumn[%
 {% important to protect the [] of the framed box  
  \begin{tabular}{l}
     Abstract tabular ...
  \end{tabular}

 \vspace{0.6cm}
  \begin{tabular}{p{18cm}}
   \begin{broadercontextbox}[backgroundcolor=broader_background]
            blala
   \end{broadercontextbox}
  \end{tabular}%
  }   
]%end of \twocolumn 

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The lengthy initial lines of code are from the publisher. You can find the link to all necessary files here. http://www.rsc.org/globalassets/05-journals-books-databases/journal-authors-reviewers/author-templates/rsc-articletemplate.zip . I didn't remove them since a) I don't know the extent of removal needed for retaining validity of the question (may be the problem goes away)  & b) As a LaTeX beginner, the complicated set-ups in abstract discouraged me to remove the relevant files included in template. An ideal solution would be something that just works with this template.

Comment: I won't do it.  Ask the publisher for professional support if you can't include my code in their template. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: I have to mention that I do not wish to begin a new page. I simply want to place the broader context frame box immediately after the abstract, and then continue onto introduction section without any pagebreak anywhere.

Comment: As I already wrote: If you put everything in the \twocolumn argument it should work. I edited the question a bit to make clearer that you should not use a second \twocolumn.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful help. Indeed it worked. Marked as accepted answer, upvoted and awarded bounty. A heartfelt thanks:)