# Bold Greek Letters

Tags: fonts, bold, greek

I am trying to make some words in greek bold, but no matter what I try fails. I use `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` because I need both greek and english in my paper and I also use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Both `\bf` and `\textbf` work fine for the english words, but when I try them on the greek words (after the `\selectlanguage{greek}` or `\textgreek` commands) they do not seem to work. The text is printed just the same as without these commands. What can I do?

Comment: Don't let use guess which fonts your document is using, make a (small), complete example.

Comment: I use [LGR,T1]{fontenc} and {textcomp,amssymb}. I am completely new to latex, so I am not sure what else you need. The template was ready and I added only the greek language.

Comment: I wrote a *complete* example. One that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document} and that we can compile to check the fonts. Regarding templates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Answer (score 3):

To long for a comment. In this minimal document bold greek works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %not needed with texlive 2018 and current miktex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

hallo Welt \textgreek{γεια κόσμο}

\bfseries hallo Welt \textgreek{γεια κόσμο}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the example fails for you and you don't get bold greek, show the log-file.

If the example works for you, you will have to find out what your document is doing differently. (I wouldn't use the utf8x-option but utf8 but this shouldn't be relevant here).

Comment: This example works fine, but I cannot see the difference with my project. I use just the same packages (apart from utf8x, because when I change it to utf8 it causes some errors- but it definitely doesn't cause the problem). Could the addition of extra packages AFTER these specific ones cause the problem and what kind of packages could they be?

Comment: You shouldn't use utf8x. If you get errors with utf8: make an example and ask how to correct them.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that the problem was caused by the package aeguill that was added later. Discarding this package, the bold greek letters appear just fine.
Thank you very much for your time and effort!