# Replace \part of the appendix of Legrand Orange Book with letters of the alphabet instead of arabic numbers

Tags: appendices, parts

I would to obtain, using the **Legrand Orange Book** source and his `structure.tex` file, an appendix (in Italian language) done only with the letters of the alphabet.

So for example:

[image]

The several parts, different from the appendix, must to start with the arabic numerals from 1, 2, 3, etc. With my long source `structure.tex` with many different `\usepackage` I can only do this after many attempts.

[image]

At the Christian Hupfer's answer I have added:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}%<------for the preface
\pagenumbering{arabic}%<------for the parts
```

and to have an `\part+\chapter` into *appendix* (`\usepackage[all options]{appendix}`) with all the alphabetical letter I have added only:

```
\appendix
\part{\textcolor{ocre}{\textsc{Appendice}}}
\chapter{Richiami di formalismo vettoriale}
```

but I have always an arabic number and I have not the letter A. I have made many attempts but I have not succeeded as can be seen from the image. Thank you in advance for yours help.

Comment: Does the file `chapter_head_9.pdf` contain the number 5?

Comment: @Sigur No, it is a picture. Should I also insert the image in pdf?

Comment: I supposed that the number could come from that image. Sorry.

Comment: @Sigur Into the code there is `\chapterimage{chapter_head_9.pdf} % Chapter heading image`.

Comment: Yes, I know. What is the image content? Maybe the number 5 is in  this image, so you can not change it to roman, except if you edit that image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Undo the changes in structure.tex from your previous question regarding part numbering or use the original structure.tex.
2. Add this to your preamble or at the end of structure.tex:

   ```
    \documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 

    \input{structure} 
     %%%NEW
     \renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}%part numbering in arabic

     \appto\appendix{%
     \renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}% A,B,C
     \renewcommand{\theHpart}{\Alph{part}}% for hyperref
     \setcounter{part}{0}} %to restart with A
     %%%% END NEW
     \begin{document}
   ```

This assumes that the appendix is at the end of the document.

A general remark: You are using a rather complex template from a *commercial* site. You can't handle this template and can't create minimal examples from it. I don't think that it is okay to expect free support in such a case. I also think that it is quite ineffective to spent hours on questions if you don't have the knowledge to create sensible minimal examples. See also [Why should you avoid using (complex) templates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-using-complex-templates/391022#391022).

Comment: First of all, I thank you for your support and for the exhaustive and effective answer. Everything works perfectly. On this site I have to know many things and the suggestions are welcome, hoping to remember them all. Well I understand your directions but all I'm doing is for the memory of my beloved and dear dad that I miss so much. I thank you and everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
\arabic{...}
```

with

```
\Alph{...}
```

Comment: If I replace for the `\part` from `\arabic{...}` with `\Alph{...}` hence all parts are all with alphabetical letters.

Comment: @Sebastiano Obviously you did it at the wrong place, but without MWE ...

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/minimal

Comment: @Sebastiano No, there are more changes

Comment: If you add a \chapter{...} there are many errors into code main.tex in attachment. For example \part{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{Appendice}}} \chapter{Richiami di formalismo vettoriale}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\chapter{Richiami di formalismo vettoriale}, this not work. I have always an arabic number.

Comment: \chapter works fine for me

Comment: Can you edit exactly my structure.tex (my true structure.tex is different) and main.tex, please?

Comment: If you would provide a minimal one without all the unrelated junk ...

Comment: I have upvoted only at this moment your answer.