# Automatic change of the color for each \part

Tags: color, typography, parts

With reference to a question previously asked,

[Replace \part of the appendix of Legrand Orange Book with letters of the alphabet instead of arabic numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432919/replace-part-of-the-appendix-of-legrand-orange-book-with-letters-of-the-alphabe)

I would like to understand which commands are necessary to alternate or change randomly the colors of each part with between 10 colors chosen at my pleasure.
I have selected only the part of the .tex file that refers to Legrande Orange Book that I considered necessary for the correct compilation of the code that I reported.

**To be more clear I would like each part to be coloured, at random, not with the same colour.**

Here's an image of two snapshots made with paint.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{mathptmx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling (this is mostly taken care of in the PART HEADINGS section of this file)
\titlecontents{part}
    [0cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{20pt}\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for parts
    {}
    {}
    {}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
    {\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {\color{ocre}} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Figure text styling
\titlecontents{figure}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for figures
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Table text styling
\titlecontents{table}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for tables
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}
    [0em] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
    {\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
    {}  
    {\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}
    [0em] % Left indentation
    {\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
    {}
    {}

% Subsection text styling (note these aren't shown by default, display them by searchings this file for tocdepth and reading the commented text)
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
    [.5em] % Left indentation
    {\sffamily\footnotesize} % Spacing and font options for subsections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
    {}
    {}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS AND FOOTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable the custom headers and footers

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Styling for the current chapter in the header
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Styling for the current section in the header

\fancyhf{} % Clear default headers and footers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Styling for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Uncomment to include a footer

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Thickness of the rule under the header

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified
    \fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}%
}

% Unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}%
}

\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\thepart}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}% The depth to which the Part mini table of contents displays headings; 0 for chapters only, 1 for chapters and sections and 2 for chapters, sections and subsections
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}


\begin{document}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}
\part{Part Two}



\end{document}
```

Comment: _Off-topic:_ You have to load `\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{tikz}` to avoid an `Option clash` error.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to introduce such a feature? Just because it is possible? Alternating colors for titles? This is not a proof of good typography.

Comment: At the moment, your document shows apricot-like colored rectangles only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I like pastel colors and in my opinion it will also provide a better aesthetic for my book. I simply extrapolated the entire code. In summary, I only took the compilable part.

Comment: My code was edited and I put `\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{tikz}` and put [tag:typography].

Comment: @Sebastiano: I doubt that pastel colors are really preferable, but as long as it is just for your personal usage...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I like very much the colors that you have chosen. Fantastic!

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, I chose them after long consideration ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the color on a random base can be done easily with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` and applying `\clist_rand_item:N` for example, which contains list of colors.

Use `\SebastianosColorList{Red,...,}` to store the color names and a `\colorlet{ocre}{\RandomColor}` to change from `ocre` to a random color.

The macro `\SebastianosRandSeed` sets the random number seed, with the given seed `12345678` and the used colors the sequence of part colors is

red, blue, yellow, brown, green (in pastel like variations)

Please note that random numbers are random in the sense that `red` could be followed by `red` as well, i.e. there is no guarantee that no repetition will occur.

Please note also that this code does not work with `XeLaTeX`, since the random number generator code of `expl3` is not working with `XeLaTeX`.

I will update the code ...

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_sebastiano_color_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\SebastianosColorList}{+m}{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_sebastiano_color_clist {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\RandomColor}{}{
  \clist_rand_item:N \g_sebastiano_color_clist
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SebastianosRandSeed}{+m}{
  \sys_gset_rand_seed:n {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling (this is mostly taken care of in the PART HEADINGS section of this file)
\titlecontents{part}
    [0cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{20pt}\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for parts
    {}
    {}
    {}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
    {\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {\color{ocre}} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Figure text styling
\titlecontents{figure}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for figures
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

% Table text styling
\titlecontents{table}
    [1.25cm] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for tables
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} % Formatting of numbered sections of this type
    {} % Formatting of numberless sections of this type
    {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Formatting of the filler to the right of the heading and the page number

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}
    [0em] % Left indentation
    {\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
    {\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
    {}  
    {\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}
    [0em] % Left indentation
    {\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
    {}
    {}

% Subsection text styling (note these aren't shown by default, display them by searchings this file for tocdepth and reading the commented text)
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
    [.5em] % Left indentation
    {\sffamily\footnotesize} % Spacing and font options for subsections
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
    {}
    {}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS AND FOOTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable the custom headers and footers

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Styling for the current chapter in the header
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Styling for the current section in the header

\fancyhf{} % Clear default headers and footers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Styling for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Uncomment to include a footer

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Thickness of the rule under the header

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified
    \fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}%
}

% Unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}%
}


\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\colorlet{ocre}{\RandomColor}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\thepart}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}% The depth to which the Part mini table of contents displays headings; 0 for chapters only, 1 for chapters and sections and 2 for chapters, sections and subsections
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}


\SebastianosRandSeed{12345678}
\SebastianosColorList{Red,Green,Yellow,Blue,Violet,Brown,Orange}


\begin{document}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}
\part{Part Two}


\part{Part Three}

\part{Part Four}

\part{Part Five}


\end{document}
```