# Issue with the numeration of the appendix B

Tags: parts, appendix

Referring to a previous request of mine as from the following link:

[Replace \part of the appendix of Legrand Orange Book with letters of the alphabet instead of arabic numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432919/replace-part-of-the-appendix-of-legrand-orange-book-with-letters-of-the-alphabe)

I can't find the solution on how to get for the appendix B, the same structure as the appendix A:

```
\appendix
\part{\textcolor{SandyBrown}{\textsc{Appendice}}}
\chapterimage{chapter_head_10.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\chapter{Richiami di formalismo vettoriale}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}%part numbering in arabic
```

Precisely for the Appendix B

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\part{\textcolor{SandyBrown}{\textsc{Appendice}}}
\chapterimage{chapter_head_10.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\chapter{Titolo per l'appendice B}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
```

it is not have the numeration B.1, B.1.1. etc.

[image]

As you can see from the image, the numbering of appendix B is missing the letter B that precedes the numbering.

How can I solve or fix the issue?

**EDIT 1: following a comment now deleted. This is the result:**

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480159/gauss-brackets-with-double-vertical-lines#comment1213325_480159

Comment: @samcarter I'd like to remind Mrs. Samcarter to keep her calm. I'm not a native speaker, but it's obvious to me that I have an MWE, when it's possible to build it I put it in immediately.  Already this morning I've been reprimanded enough and that posted link has absolutely no meaning. I kindly ask you to stop the controversy and instrumentalization, thank you.

Comment: @samcarter I've never offended anyone in my life. I have only expressed my point of view. I respect myself and others and there is no need for anyone to remind me of that. But it is enough to continue with these controversies. I only ask for peace and serenity.  Be more careful of other users as well. I greet you and have a good evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the settings in your code

```
\appendix
\part{\textcolor{SandyBrown}{\textsc{Appendice}}}
\chapterimage{chapter_head_10.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\chapter{Richiami di formalismo vettoriale}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}%part numbering in arabic
```

most things are done that are needed if you add an second appendix B. So only the following code for appendix B is needed:

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\part{\textcolor{SandyBrown}{\textsc{Appendice}}}
\chapterimage{chapter_head_10.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\chapter{Titolo per l'appendice B}
```

Usually line `\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}` should not be needed, but I guess -- I do not know your used template -- your used template redefined it somewhere before ...