# biblatex doesnt work

Tags: biblatex

i have a question. I am using bibaltex to create a bibliography, or rather I try to use it. This is what i have:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\begin{document}
Text\cite{"Bibtexkey"}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I dont get any errors. The bibtexkey appears, where i wrote \cite... (actually a number should appear), but no bibliography.

Can anyone help?

Best
Roy

Comment: Don't use quotes " inside \cite. Did you call biber? Does the blg show any error?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751) if you're not sure how to run `biber` on the file.

Comment: Quotes are indees suspicious, but I'm not sure if this is for illustrative purposes or the real deal. Any how, you need to run Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you want your editor to do that for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: @Bobyandbob Adding a boilerplate request for a MWEB when there's already a MWE isn't exactly helpful. As our other comments have suggested, it's most likely that this is simply a case of not having run `biber` in which case the MWEB is superfluous.

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree, but from my point of view creating a mweb is always helpful. Only with a mwe or a mweb other people could provide feedback "I get the same" or "works fine with calling biber or what else ... ".

Comment: @AlanMunn A real, complete example would allow to disregard a lot of other possible source of problems (e.g. if the quotes are real, bib keys with spaces, clashing packages etc) so imho it would be quite useful here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, i am using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/caltech-thesis-latex-template-with-logo/kgwqvkbfkwmx#.WwcHUvZFzIU

Comment: And i dont use "" inside cite and i am also running Biber.

Comment: Sorry I won't debug a template from another site and try to guess what you could be doing wrong when using it. You will have to show a real minimal example with log-files *here*. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-using-complex-templates/391022#391022

Comment: So i have to write my own file. But thanks to trying to help me.

Comment: The template you link to uses `biblatex` and works out of the box. Do you compile the document on Overleaf or on your local machine? What did you change? Do you get any LaTeX errors or wrabnings? Did you run Biber? If you ran Biber there should be a `.blg` file, what does it say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.

Comment: Any news here? As I said in my comment above, things should work. But you need to run Biber on your file. See my first comment above.

Comment: Any news here? Currently this is a duplicate of the "run Biber" question.