# Chapter beginning with a full-size image

Tags: fonts, graphics

I'm very new to LaTex and I'm writing my thesis using the Tufte style book template.

I like this template but I would like to change the style of the chapter title page.

Now the beginning of a chapter looks like this:

[image]

What I would like instead is this:

[image]
[image]

That is a first page that contains a full page image and its label and a second page that contains the number and the title of the chapter (in capse lock the number and in bold the title) and the text.

I would also like to use [this font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans). How can I do?

I looked like what I want but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Tufte-LaTeX heavily redefines many aspects of LaTeX. It tries to reproduce the layout of some well-known books (including fonts etc.) and not to change them. To modify this you need to change the internal definitions which does not sound like a good idea. If you do not have to use tufte, you could build something on your own (with the features of Tufte you would like to use). For OpenSans (which I personally would not recommend) have a look at Xe-/LuaLaTeX. Anyway, please always include a minimal, compilable code example (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: Mandatory link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/124577

Comment: Since this is your first post I think that you're new to (La)TeX world. In this case you should start from plain LaTeX, without template and create your template. Tufte styles (there are three of them) are very beautiful, imho, and I've used them more than once but their purpose is to replicate some well-known books (as said by TeXnician). You could do some minor changes and include the packages you need, of course, but if you need some changes to the layout you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Since you like tufte book style, my advice is: check the [book example on CTAN](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf), take note of what are the things that you like about it, try to include that feature in your own template, if you're not able to do it then post a mwe asking for help for that feature.

Comment: Also, regarding fonts, there are a few consideration that you should consider: you should use roman family as main font family (that is for your text), sans serif fonts could be used for anything that is not a long block of text (titles, tables, and so on), the font you choose (unless you know what you're doing) should have all the three families and math support, to use external font you should use XeLaTeX.

Comment: @gvgramazio Or LuaLaTeX as I've already written above. Both have up- and downsides especially when it comes to compilation of material that relies on DVI/PDF-based flow.