# Problem: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: errors, size

i downloaded [this TeX example](https://studi-lektor.de/lektorat/latex-vorlagen.html) to begin with the documentation of my thesis. I changed nothing and tried to compile it. But i got this error on line 41 and there is only this comment. % Paket für Boxen im Text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390683/35864 and (since you seem to speak German) https://komascript.de/latexvorlage

Comment: For starters `\usepackage{ngerman}` (in `Hauptdatei.tex`) has been superseded by `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (which is also loaded immediately afterwards) many moons ago and I have seen it cause trouble in complex documents. So you should get rid of `\usepackage{ngerman}`. `fancyhdr` with KOMA script classes is usually not a great idea. With KOMA classes you can use `scrlayer-scrpage`. These empty `\section*{ }` also look very suspicious to me.

Comment: Indeed removing `\usepackage{ngerman}` almost lets me compile the code. I now get a `! Class scrartcl Error: undefined old font command `\tt'.` because the example uses `\tt` which has been deprecated for more than 20 years (https://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-2letterfontcmd.html) now. If I replace the `\tt` by `\ttfamily` everything works as expected.