# Problem with UTF-8 in Listings not beingsolved by standard answer

Tags: listings, input-encodings

I'm using TeXstudio and pdfLaTeX. I'm trying to use the *listings* package to add some Matlab source code to my document. However, I'm having trouble with some portuguese letters used in the code (graphics captions, actually).

The common answer to this known encoding problem is shown [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Encoding_issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116266/listings-in-latex-with-utf-8-or-at-least-german-umlauts). However, even after adding the `\lstset{literate=}` with the correct list, the problem persists. I verified that the problematic letters and indeed in the list to be substituted, but no change.

The `\lstset` and the `\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{estrutura/dados/algoritmos/main.m}` I'm calling to add the code are in different files, but that was not a problem for any other package. I also verified that I can include code without any special characters.

What could be causing this problem and what would be a fix or an workaround?

Thanks for any help

EDIT for sample code:
This part is the one being used to substitute letters in the listings.

```
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 {Á}{{\'A}}1 
    {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1
    {Ú}{{\'U}}1 {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 
    {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1
    {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 
    {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1
    {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1 {Â}{{\^A}}1
    {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1
    {Û}{{\^U}}1 {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1
    {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 
    {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1
    {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1 {»}{{\guillemotright}}1
    {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
}
```

This is the line calling listing of the source code

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{estrutura/dados/algoritmos/plot_bf_compare_in_out.m}
```

Specifically, the section of Matlab code throwing the error is

```
title("Comparação entre áudio antes e depois do beamformer");
```

EDIT 2: Since the complete text I am working is spread across multriple files and folders, I recreated the minimum document with everything that seems relevant to this problem and throws the same error. OneDrive download link [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!At6EzNfnhhj1g5B64LyB13ETkHI1QQ) with the files.

EDIT 3: 
Compilable LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[%twoside,                   % Impressão em frente e verso
oneside,                   % Impressão apenas frente
]{utfpr-abntex2}


\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                   
\usepackage{booktabs}                                      
\usepackage{color, colortbl}                                
\usepackage{float}                                          
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       
\usepackage{icomma}                                         
\usepackage{indentfirst}                                    
\usepackage{microtype}                                      
\usepackage{multirow, array}                                
\usepackage{subeqnarray}                                    
\usepackage{lastpage}                                       
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{verbatim}                                       
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}                     
\usepackage[algoruled, portuguese]{algorithm2e}             
\usepackage{times}                                  
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}                       
\usepackage{ae, aecompl}                                    
\usepackage{latexsym}                                      
\usepackage{lscape}                                         
\usepackage{picinpar}                                      
\usepackage{scalefnt}                                      
\usepackage{upgreek}                                      
\usepackage{listings}

% Parte utilizada para que códigos fonte possam conter caracteres em português
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 {Á}{{\'A}}1 
    {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1
    {Ú}{{\'U}}1 {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 
    {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1
    {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 
    {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1
    {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1 {Â}{{\^A}}1
    {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1
    {Û}{{\^U}}1 {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1
    {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 
    {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1
    {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{plot_bf_compare_in_out.m} 

\end{document}
```

Sample of problematic source code file (.m):

```
figure;
title("Comparação entre áudio antes e depois do beamformer");
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It will be quite hard to help you without seeing some example code. Can you please edit your question to include a minimal compilable document that reproduces the problem you're having. (Also, the easiest way to deal with UTF-8 listings is to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: As Alan said, is there any reason not to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: XeLaTeX doesn't throw errors, but just ignores any letter it doesn't know. LuaLaTeX gives the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this isn't compilable code. Can you put it into a document that begins with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`.  And we can't see your actual `\lstinputlisting` file, so please include some of it directly in the document or add a small sample file to the question too.

Comment: Since the files are to big and spread, I put all the configuration in a new file and added a link to download the .tex file and the .m file with the code. Link in EDIT 2

Comment: No, we don't need your exact files. You need to show us a small file  in your question (not a link) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking that isn't already in the edit. I have the line `\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{estrutura/dados/algoritmos/plot_bf_compare_in_out.m}  
`  that calls to source code file and the line `title("Comparação entre áudio antes e depois do beamformer");
` in the source code itself, with the character that causes the error.

Comment: Added another EDIT. Hopefully that has the information you are looking for

Comment: What do you mean "just ignores any letter is doesn't know?" It makes no sense. If there is no glyph in a font, it just doesn't use it, that's all, find another font.

Comment: XeLaTeX just doesn't put the letter. So if I write "Seção", all that it shows is "Seo". I'm not sure what you mean by "glyph". I'm still new to LaTeX and using a template for this kind of work that complies with all font and formatting standards.

Comment: @L.Farinha, no, if you just write `\begin{document} Não nènínónnã. \end{document} and compile with XeLaTeX, no strings attached, it will render fine. That is, unless you're doing something we don't know, since you didn't show us a minimal working example. Using templates sometimes is not the best way to learn -- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-using-complex-templates

Comment: It was working fine for that case. The problem only happened when using the "listings" package. My EDIT 3 included the minimum working example. All those packages might not be needed, but I decided to include them, in case one could be conflicting with another. About the template, if I was not using it there would not be a reason to use LaTeX for this. Not having to worry with all the small formatting details needed for a thesis like this.

Comment: I see you're loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` twice (is this really a "template"?). These packages wouldn't be needed if you use `xelatex`. Besides, there are many reasons to use LaTeX and *not* using that template without any modifications.

Comment: Not sure if "template" is the correct word for this. It's a group of files configurated and separated by section according to the rules for academic thesis where I live. Basically, everything was already created and you just delete the sample text to add your own. There are instructions and examples on how to add figures and tables and orientation on the correct way to add references to the bibliography. I'm not touching the default packages. I use LaTeX for other stuff too and start from a blank page, but in this case this was the fastest way to finish my thesis.

Comment: "I'm not touching the default packages." -- Even if those packages are loaded twice, are deprecated or obsolete?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the input encoding from utf8 to latin1 only in the listings. In the end, I got this as the settings for the listings and it worked.

```
\lstset{
language=Matlab,
inputencoding=latin1,
extendedchars=true,
literate=
    {é}{{\'{e}}}1
    {è}{{\`{e}}}1
    {ê}{{\^{e}}}1
    {ë}{{\¨{e}}}1
    {É}{{\'{E}}}1
    {Ê}{{\^{E}}}1
    {û}{{\^{u}}}1
    {ù}{{\`{u}}}1
    {ú}{{\'{u}}}1
    {â}{{\^{a}}}1
    {à}{{\`{a}}}1
    {á}{{\'{a}}}1
    {ã}{{\~{a}}}1
    {Á}{{\'{A}}}1
    {Â}{{\^{A}}}1
    {Ã}{{\~{A}}}1
    {ç}{{\c{c}}}1
    {Ç}{{\c{C}}}1
    {õ}{{\~{o}}}1
    {ó}{{\'{o}}}1
    {ô}{{\^{o}}}1
    {Õ}{{\~{O}}}1
    {Ó}{{\'{O}}}1
    {Ô}{{\^{O}}}1
    {î}{{\^{i}}}1
    {Î}{{\^{I}}}1
    {í}{{\'{i}}}1
    {Í}{{\~{Í}}}1
}
```