# Placing the little orange square at the end of the Exercise environment from Legrand Book Orange template

Tags: spacing, floats, positioning, page-breaking

I wrote the notes of one of my courses using the very nice Legrand book template, but I have a little problem with those little orange squares at the end of the exercises. When I write `\begin{exercise} .. \end{exercise}`, the little square at the end of the box is sometimes badly placed.

Precisely, if the exercise ends with a formula like `\[ ... \]` or a list `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` then that little square goes to the next line. That, in a few cases, means that it goes on the next page, making the exercise box split into two pages, with just that little orange square on the second page, very bad.

I fixed a similar issue with the bigger black box of the 
`\begin{proof} .. \end{proof}` environment by placing a `\qedhere` inside the  `\[ ... \]`, but the same command does not have any effect inside a `\begin{exercise} .. \end{exercise}` environment.

I have the same problem with the `\begin{example} .. \end{example}` environment. Is there any command like  `\qedhere`  working there?

Edit: reading an answer to a different question here I tried to put `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before the `\end{exercise}`. The result was unexpected: the orange box reduced exactly of the expected amount but the square remains were it is, so it is now out of the box!

Edit 2: The  screenshot

[image: Example]

is my try to produce a *minimal but complete example* as requested by @@CarLaTeX in the comments. I produced it by using the online Legrand Orange Book Template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/the-legrand-orange-book-template-english/jtctyfmnpppc):

```
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.1.1 (14/2/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Compiling this template:
% This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
% When you first open the template, compile it from the command line with the 
% commands below to make sure your LaTeX distribution is configured correctly:
%
% 1) pdflatex main
% 2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
% 3) biber main
% 4) pdflatex main x 2
%
% After this, when you wish to update the bibliography/index use the appropriate
% command above and make sure to compile with pdflatex several times 
% afterwards to propagate your changes to the document.
%
% This template also uses a number of packages which may need to be
% updated to the newest versions for the template to compile. It is strongly
% recommended you update your LaTeX distribution if you have any
% compilation errors.
%
% Important note:
% Chapter heading images should have a 2:1 width:height ratio,
% e.g. 920px width and 460px height.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate [below=12cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}}; % Background image
\draw[anchor=north] (midpoint) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

\begin{exercise}
Show that, for every smooth function $f \colon U \Rightarrow {\mathbb K}$ and for every $p \in U$,
\[
df_p=\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p) (dx_i)_p.
\]
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Citation}\index{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{book_key}; this one is more specific \cite[122]{article_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Name] Description
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
In $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent. It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. 
\end{theorem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Notations}\index{Notations}

\begin{notation}
Given an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of functions $\varphi$ are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bounded support $G$;
\item Infinitely differentiable;
\end{enumerate}
a vector space is denoted by $\mathcal{D}(G)$. 
\end{notation}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}

This is an example of a remark.

\begin{remark}
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{remark}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\begin{corollary}[Corollary name]
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{corollary}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition name]
It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $f,g\in L^2(G)$; if $\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(G)$, $(f,\varphi)_0=(g,\varphi)_0$ then $f = g$. 
\end{proposition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\begin{example}
Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<3\}$ and denoted by: $x^0=(1,1)$; consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} & \mathrm{e}^{|x|} & & \text{si $|x-x^0|\leq 1/2$}\\
& 0 & & \text{si $|x-x^0|> 1/2$}\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ has bounded support, we can take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x-x^0|\leq 1/2+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon\in\intoo{0}{5/2-\sqrt{2}}$.
\end{example}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\begin{example}[Example name]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\begin{problem}
What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{problem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\begin{vocabulary}[Word]
Definition of word.
\end{vocabulary}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part Two}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 3
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Presenting Information}

\section{Table}\index{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `$...$` instead of `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Thanks. That would work, of course, but this is not really optimal, because I have sometimes complicated formulas that deserve a different environment. There is no other solution?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal but _complete_ example which reproduces your problem?

Comment: Hi Carla, thanks for your answer. I added a picture at the beginning with a "minimal" example, is that what you meant?

Comment: @RobertoPignatelli For example I have not a log never in Overleaf. I use often the same template. I think that your code (as MWE) is poor and incomplete. I would help you but I know that the structure of this template is very long. The Legrand Orange Book structure is the default into Overleaf.

Comment: @Sebastiano Ok, I put the whole code right now.

Comment: @RobertoPignatelli kind Roberto, If I didn't misunderstand your question, would you like the orange box of the exercise not to be broken into two parts? I have the same problem, too, but I don't think it's relevant. My dear and esteemed Christian Hupfer user has always warned me to use this type of template. All the code in the structure.tex file is linked to each other and it's complex to crop a box without it going to the other page. I don't think you have to worry about it at all and the possible resolution of the problem will surely have to be solved by users much better than me.

Comment: You are *not* showing the whole code. Your file inputs a `structure.tex` which we don't have (and which naturally contains the definition of the problematic environment). I won't download the template, get this probably quite large file and then go through the code to find the relevant parts. Create a real, complete, self contained minimal example which you can post here or ask the people who wrote the template for support. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, this is really worst template I have ever seen. Don't use it unless it is the only chance to safe your life. If someone is forcing you at gun point to use this template, then you could workaround the problem shown in the question by enlarging the page in question by one line. In all other situations, the problem is best solved by deleting all files are associated with this template.

(placing a square at the end of an exercise is also very strange, it should only be placed at the end of proofs...)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.1.1 (14/2/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Compiling this template:
% This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
% When you first open the template, compile it from the command line with the 
% commands below to make sure your LaTeX distribution is configured correctly:
%
% 1) pdflatex main
% 2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
% 3) biber main
% 4) pdflatex main x 2
%
% After this, when you wish to update the bibliography/index use the appropriate
% command above and make sure to compile with pdflatex several times 
% afterwards to propagate your changes to the document.
%
% This template also uses a number of packages which may need to be
% updated to the newest versions for the template to compile. It is strongly
% recommended you update your LaTeX distribution if you have any
% compilation errors.
%
% Important note:
% Chapter heading images should have a 2:1 width:height ratio,
% e.g. 920px width and 460px height.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate [below=12cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}}; % Background image
\draw[anchor=north] (midpoint) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

Just a line.

\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\begin{exercise}
Show that, for every smooth function $f \colon U \Rightarrow {\mathbb K}$ and for every $p \in U$,
\[
df_p=\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p) (dx_i)_p.
\]
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Citation}\index{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{book_key}; this one is more specific \cite[122]{article_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Name] Description
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
In $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent. It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. 
\end{theorem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Notations}\index{Notations}

\begin{notation}
Given an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of functions $\varphi$ are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bounded support $G$;
\item Infinitely differentiable;
\end{enumerate}
a vector space is denoted by $\mathcal{D}(G)$. 
\end{notation}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}

This is an example of a remark.

\begin{remark}
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{remark}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\begin{corollary}[Corollary name]
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{corollary}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition name]
It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $f,g\in L^2(G)$; if $\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(G)$, $(f,\varphi)_0=(g,\varphi)_0$ then $f = g$. 
\end{proposition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\begin{example}
Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<3\}$ and denoted by: $x^0=(1,1)$; consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} & \mathrm{e}^{|x|} & & \text{si $|x-x^0|\leq 1/2$}\\
& 0 & & \text{si $|x-x^0|> 1/2$}\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ has bounded support, we can take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x-x^0|\leq 1/2+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon\in\intoo{0}{5/2-\sqrt{2}}$.
\end{example}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\begin{example}[Example name]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\begin{problem}
What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{problem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\begin{vocabulary}[Word]
Definition of word.
\end{vocabulary}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part Two}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 3
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Presenting Information}

\section{Table}\index{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the best template for you? We'd love to learn to use it.

Comment: Could you please highlight where exactly you made changes in the very long code provided?

Comment: @ferahfeza The best thing is to not use a template, just one of the standard classes. This allows you to learn as you go along and write your document without picking up such bad habits as shown in the template.

Comment: @guest I know that using templates is worse than writing by self (but I don't say it is bad, especially for new LaTeXers). But that does not mean every templates is bad. I have seen many badly-organized templates, but this orange one is cool IMHO.

Comment: @HenriMenke He adds the line `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` before the `exercise` environment.

Comment: That's a very fragile work around as it has to be adapted everytime the document changes. A real solution should correct the definition of the environment.