# Questions about the usage of a Lyx thesis template

Tags: lyx, templates, thesis, xecjk

I am trying to start writing my doctoral thesis using a Lyx template. The download link is: https://code.google.com/archive/p/thuthesislyx/downloads

However, many errors pop up when I try to compile the `main.lyx`. Some of them are:

```
 \ProcessKeysOptions { xeCJK / options }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
| 
| Try typing <return> to proceed.
| If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
|...............................................



 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

These errors make me really frustrated. Can anyone give me some clues about where to start? Thank you so much!

---

Edit 1: I export a `.tex` file from the `.lyx` file, and the major error seems to be:

```
! xeCJK error: "key-unknown"
! 
! Sorry, but xeCJK/options does not have a key called `ItalicFont'.
! 
! The key `ItalicFont' is being ignored.
! 
! See the xeCJK documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................  

l.4389 \ProcessKeysOptions { xeCJK / options }

?
```

Comment: It is madness to try to use a 6 years old template without any support if you are not very good at latex and lyx debugging. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: If you are just looking for LyX thesis templates, you could also try https://github.com/scottkosty/lyx-princeton-diss