# Remove rulers from draft view

Tags: formatting, header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, draft

I plan to use this document template for constructing my thesis:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

However, when running in draft mode, multiple rulers appear in the header and im unable to find whats causing them. Could someone explain why they are there and how to remove them?

regards,
Phil

[image: Rulers appear when using draft mode]

Comment: I won't download a zip-file from an external site to debug it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I have downloaded the zip file and ran it; it has no problems and these rulers were never shown. Can you please elaborate on how you achieved this result (in terms of you TeX distribution or did you use Overleaf).

Comment: @M.AlJumaily the rulers only appear when draft mode is selected as an option in line 30 of the main.tex file and the rulers appear on page 3 onwards.

I am compiling with texworks

Comment: @esdd has the answer which works!

Comment: Or you could just not use a KOMA document class.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The OP does not use a KOMA-Script class: `book` is a standard class. There are many other packages providing a `draft` option which can result in unwanted effects too. But with a KOMA-Script class the class option `draft` could be replaced by the class option `overfullrule` to avoid such effects.

Answer (score 6):

Your class loads package `scrlayer-scrpage` which adds the rulers if option `draft` is set. To disable the draft mode for package `scrlayer-scrpage` add `\KOMAoptions{draft=false}` to your preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\KOMAoptions{draft=false}% <- disables the draft mode for scrlayer-scrpage

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The document class file contains this on line 278

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

By changing to

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used, draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

It removes the rulers in draft mode.