# Why tcolorbox crash with caption?

Tags: tcolorbox

Any idea what is the use of:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
```

in simple explanation?

This is because I need to include `\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}`, but it crash with `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`. 
I need to delete `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`.

Why both are crash?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}



\begin{document}
```

Comment: The error message you show is because you added `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to your preamble. The error message is shown, since `uorthesis` already loads the `graphicx` package. If you want to use the `demo` option, include it into the class options (´\documentclass[12pt, oneside, demo]{book}`).

Comment: However, the incompatibility between `subcaption` and `uorthesis` still persists. Therefore, your MWE will still produce error messages, even after fixing what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks! I cancel off `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, it works. Can i know how you read the error message? I need to learn instead of struggle finding it

Comment: This information is literally written in the red box you showed in your screenshot: "The package graphicx has already been loaded with options:
[]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[demo]
Adding the global options:
,demo
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this."

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. Can i know what is the meaning of `the incompatibility between subcaption and uorthesis still persists`? I already cancel off `subcaption` in my `uorthesis`.

Comment: What does "I already cancel off subcaption in my uorthesis"  mean? You still load both packages `uorthesis` and `subcaption`.

Comment: @leandriis. `uorthesis` is just a list of `usepackage` and does not contain any `subcaption`.

Comment: That's true. but `uorthesis` contains `\usepackage{subfigure}`.  And `subfigure` (loaded by `uorthesis`)  and `subcaption` (loaded in your preamble) are incompatible.

Comment: @leadriis, thanks for that. I also cancel off `subfigure` in the `uorthesis` file. Between, now i cancel off `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, will it create lots of problem? What is `grahicx` use for?

Comment: Instead of manipilating packages (which you do when you delete lines from a .sty file)  you should consider completely dropping the `uorthesis` package. Instead, copy the absolutely necessary lines from `uorthesis` package to your preamble. Regarding templates and the use of such, you might want to have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390684/134144

Comment: The `graphicx` package is needed to include images into your document using the `\includegraphics` command.