# finding file which is generating error in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am having a latex document with a template which was given to me by some one.I have 205 errors that I see in overleaf document.
the statements give me a link to follow ,that link is following
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Undefined_control_sequence
I see following statement

```
\begin{document}
```

where I see errors it says thesis.tex line 367

The files I have are following names 
dir /b
the output is following in thesis folder

```
biblio.bib
tg.cls
itglogo-eps-converted-to.pdf
itglogo.eps
logo-eps-converted-to.pdf
README.md
STYLES (directory)
texfiles (directory)
thesis.aux
thesis.idx
thesis.lof
thesis.log
thesis.lot
thesis.out
thesis.pdf
thesis.synctex.gz
thesis.tex
thesis.toc
```

there are a lot of files in subdirectory texfiles

```
abrreviation.tex
abstract.tex
abstract.tex.backup
abstract.tex~
acknowledgments.tex
acknowledgments.tex~
arydshln.sty
bibthesis.bib
chapter1.log
chapter1.tex
chapter2.tex
chapter3.tex
chapter4.tex
chapter5.tex
chapter6.tex
conclusion.tex
conclusion.tex~
cv.tex
cv.tex~
images
symbol.tex
thesis.bib.backup
thesis.bib~
```

Here is a screenshot 
[image: error document for begin]

I am not able to understand how do I debug it?
What can I do to remove the errors.
This was a custom template some one got from another university and gave it to us.
We do not have an IT or library department to ask questions as what is it doing.Which files there are errors what are the errors.
here is a link to all the files you can see it
https://www.overleaf.com/3838449319pjhnfzpgvypm

Comment: Well my main advice here is: don't use a complex, unknown template if you don't know how to debug it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388.

Comment: the error is most likely in the `.aux` file (hard to tell from what you have posted) but also does that screenshot mean you have all those styles in a local directory? If so, why? they are almost all standard packages thar are in texlive so available in overleaf.

Comment: here is the full link to all the files you can see every thing and edit it https://www.overleaf.com/3838449319pjhnfzpgvypm I basically want to know what is the problem in template,my department gave this and most of the people are using it I am myself new very new to latex. I some how have a difficult situation because I have double load than rest of the students. I do not know what is missing and what I need to do. write in it.

Comment: really that template makes no sense at all, do you have to use it, why does it contain  all those files in the styles directory?

Comment: I have no idea I have to use it , I submitted a document made from that because I was asked to do it. I got very poor grades also.

Comment: someone probably got a template from someone and they forwarded that to us,the person who forwarded the template does not know what to do with it or was too lazy to edit that and this came to us. I wish if I can get an advisor online to ask what to do each time I get an error.

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: @yo ok thanks I have sent an email with more details