# using hyperref and breakurl package inside a template red square boxes in table of contents

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, hyperref

In the lines 192,193 of project I have following lines are in the original template given by department (I did not touched them they are as it is)

```
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

and lines 85 to 88 is what I added to break long urls in bibliography.

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
```

The problem is now I get option clash for package hyperref.I am doing this in overleaf.
The package is defined two times.
In this case what should I do so that in bibliography I can get the URLs in next line without any problem.
If I comment line 193 with % and then I generate the pdf then the problem is that all table of contents,table of figures and lists have red color square boxes around them.
Here is a screenshot
[image: red square boxes in table of contents]
The template which department gave me can be seen here on this [link](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template) full.
So that if some thing I should have mentioned but I did not then you can see [thesis.tex](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template/blob/master/thesis.tex) file,
on above link.

Comment: Remove the first call to hyperref.

Comment: you shouldn't link to some external template. Such links will be dead at some time and the question no longer useful. This here is also not the right place to ask people to debug some template. If your department gave you a template they should also offer support for it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388