# Options passed to \documentclass not recognised

Tags: errors, class-options, documentclass

I am using latex to write my thesis and I am using a template with a modified class.
Since last Wednesday, the options that I declare at the top of the document in the `\documentclass` command are not recognized.

The class is coded to accept in input several options, such as font, margins, paper size, etc.
However, it seems that no option is recognized anymore.

For example, if I define

```
\documentclass[times]{ThesisClass}
```

I receive a warning that says that no font was specified.

The suspicious thing is that if I recompile the same files on a different laptop, everything works fine.

I am using Texlive2020 and TexMaker as editor on Windows 10 I already tried to update everything, wipe and re-install, but I still get the same problem.

I have tried to look online for a possible solution, but I can't find it.
Could someone please help me?

Is there a way to fix this `\documentclass` issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Main code example**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{Classes/ThesisClass}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**ThesisClass**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Classes/ThesisClass}

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{book}}%
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{book}}%
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{book}}%
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}%

% Process options and load class
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{book}
```

Comment: without the code of the class it is quite impossible to help. But generally it is not a good idea to use a local, unknown template if you don't know lot of latex. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not a problem related to the class, but in general it is \documentclass that no longer passes the options. I have tried with standard classes such as article or book and I have the same problem. I don't think I know a lot of latex, but you are simply assuming something not true. I am using a template for my thesis which is common to many users. There is no need to re-invet the wheel all the times...

Comment: What did I assume that is not true? You write in your question that you use as class  `ThesisClass` and this is not part of a standard tex system. If you can reproduce your problem with a standard class and standard packages, show a small, but complete example that can be used for tests along with the log-file of the example.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the second part of the comment (from the "But..."). I have added a simple code and the very first lines of the class that I am using. Even just changing the font size is not recognized. That is happening since the last update. On a different laptop, with an earlier version of Texlive2020, everything works smoothly.

Comment: @granprix This is a known issue when loading class and package files with an explicit path (see [the issue tracker here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422), a [related issue with a possible workaround](https://github.com/ho-tex/kvoptions/issues/8) and [another possible workaround](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-November/046316.html)).  I'm working on a fix for it, but meanwhile you'll need to use one of the workarounds.  I'll notify you when this is fixed.

Comment: Many thanks! I moved class and main to the same folder and it works (even the complex version).

Comment: while I suspected from the begin that your problem is related to the issue: remark that your question didn't contain any indication that you are loading the class from a different folder. You even explicitly wrote `\documentclass[times]{ThesisClass}`. If you have a problem it is important that you show real code, not something you think is equivalent.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just ran into this too. Should this already be fixed on pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex 2020.11.30) because it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @rzach It's already fixed in the development repo (see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/438), but we haven't released it yet, as there still are some issues pending.  The current expectation is to release in about two weeks