# \footcite[]{} indented more than \footcite[][]{}

Tags: formatting, citing, footnotes, footcite

Dear TEXstack community,

I have a problem with `\footcite`.

For direct quotations I'm using:

`\footcite[p. xy]{reference}`

For indirect quotations I'm using:

`\footcite[Vgl.][S. xy]{Quelle}`

Footmisc is integrated as follows:

`\usepackage[hang, multiple]{footmisc}`

`\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}`

Unfortunately, the footnotes of indirect quotations are indented a bit more than direct quotations:
[image]

This git repo contains the example code:
https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template

**How can I achieve consistent indentation?**

I have now searched for several hours, but have not found a suitable solution :(

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Show a small but *complete* example.

Comment: Added the screenshot. Which additional information would be helpful?

Comment: No, you should show a real document, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}. Something that we can try to reproduce the issue without having to guess which fonts you use, or which bibliography package. If possible use bib entries from e.g. biblatex-examples.bib.

Comment: Thanks for the support! This helped a lot. A template can be found here:
[link](https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template)
It contains all files, including a bib example (not the one you mentioned, but it will hopefully do the job).
Will add it to my question, too.

Comment: No, make a *small*  example that you can copy here in your question. I won't start to debug some large template. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction! I reduced everything to the bare minimum (to provide a valid example), updated a few packages and cleared all non-necessary files again (logs etc.). Result: Issue solved. After merging everything back, the issue is still solved. Again: Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might have been related to https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template/issues/186, which was reported and fixed a few days ago. If you updated your template when you tried to build the MWE that could explain it.

Comment: In any case, I'll vote to close the question, since it does not contain code to reproduce the issue and it was resolved by a number of steps that cannot easily be retraced and are thus probably not immediately helpful for future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: Hrmm, ... the banner says the question is closed because it is off-topic, but let me just emphasise that a question like this is not off-topic *per se*. It's just that the question is not self-contained and the problem cannot be easily reproduced with the information given so far and that it turned out that the problem somehow resolved itself while creating an MWE. That means that the question is unlikely to be useful for future visitors, so it was closed. The system, however, somehow groups this close reason under *off-topic*, which may give a wrong impression.

Comment: @moewe: You're 100% right with your guess that it was related to github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template/issues/186 ! As a step in between, I compared my files to the newest files in the repo and saw that the "%" was missing in my version - I haven't paid attention to it, because I thought I removed it by mistake in the debugging/copying-back-and-forth process and just added it, but didn't compile afterwards. So I missed that this already fixed it *facepalm* Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a missing "%" and was fixed already in the template (see: github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template/issues/186)

Old version with bug:

```latex
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}
        \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
      \printfield{usera}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

Fixed version:

```latex
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}%        
        \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
      \printfield{usera}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

The fixed version contains a % at the end of  line 6: *{\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}*