# How to change elegantbook biblatex reference.bib

Tags: biblatex

I just start to use elegantbook.
But the macro always ask for reference.bib as the source of citation reference, whereas
my Medeley always generate library.bib. Both cannot allow file name change.
How can I change the reference.bib of elegantbook?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you could add your resources with a label `\addbibresource[label=main]{library.bib}` and then 
start your document with `\refsection[main]`. But personally I wouldn't recommend such a template. It is better to copy the parts you like and build your own template. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `\addbibresource[location=local]{reference.bib}` (found in elegantbook.cls, line 1102) to `\addbibresource[location=local]{library.bib}`.

There are probably other ways to override this, too, but this should work.

Comment: I tried ...no use...

Comment: @nana You will have to rerun the compilation cycle LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX after the change (here "LaTeX" stands for the appropriate flavour of LaTeX and can be pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on configuring your editor for Biber (in case you haven't set it up for Biber and it still runs BibTeX for you).

Comment: That said, a class file that hard-codes the `.bib` file name is quite inflexible and not what I would consider best practice.

Comment: I have re-run for several times. The error message is still the same "cannot find reference.bib"

Comment: I investigated the source code of elegantbook myself. The reference.bib is added using \addbibresource[location=local]{reference.bib}. There is no way to change or remove this command unless I modify the source code. I have to conclude this package is pretty stupid.