# Numbering issue in \printnomenclature in latex

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

Here is the link to the latex template that I am using: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/iitmdissertation-the-official-latex-template-for-theses-synopses-and-project-reports-in-iit-madras/pbrrtcygybkj

I am using the following category: \documentclass[phd,smplmath,zdraft]{iitmdissertation}

In Notation page [around page xv], if the list of notations goes beyond one pages then the pages after the first page (under notation category) stops getting any numbers (except the last page of notation).

I track down the corresponding code in .sty file (given below) and tried to change few things like adding \newpage or using long table but it didn't worked.

```
\begin{singlespacing}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[title={\textupper{Glossary}}]
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={\textupper{Abbreviations}}]
\end{singlespacing}
\par
}
%
%
% Notations
%
%
\newcommand\addNotationDefinitions{
\input 1-frontmatter/front-notation
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation}
}

\newcommand\printNotation{%
\addNotationDefinitions\par
\begin{singlespacing}
\printnomenclature
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{singlespacing}\par
}
```

Can you please suggest any solution to this problem ? I want each page under Notations category to be numbered. I provided the link to template as the file is huge so cannot create a dummy version.

In case you need a dummy list of notations for multiple pages

```
\nomenclature{$\pi$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter}
\nomenclature{$\tau$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$c$}{the speed of light in vacuum}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{0}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{1}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{2}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{3}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{4}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{5}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{6}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{7}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{8}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{9}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{10}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{11}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{12}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{13}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{14}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{15}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{16}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{17}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{18}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{19}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{20}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{21}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{22}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{23}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{24}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{25}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{26}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{27}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{28}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{29}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{30}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{31}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{32}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{33}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{34}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{35}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{36}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{37}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{38}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{39}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{40}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{41}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{42}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{43}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{44}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
\nomenclature{$\tau_{45}$}{ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius}
```

Comment: That the template is huge is not an argument, you are getting here help for free and shouldn't simply dump such a template from an external link on people. Ask the author of the template for support if you can't handle it.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am sorry that I refer to such a huge template. I thought maybe the piece of latex script that I posted would be sufficient to solve the problem especially\printnomenclature part. If you can refer any link related to this problem, it would be helpful. I tried some but it didn't worked