# Change chapter title size in Dissertate (or prevent long chapter title pagebreak)

Tags: chapters, section-titles, dissertate

When using the `Dissertate` template/class for a dissertation, longer chapter titles cause formatting issues (chapter titles get moved onto the page after the chapter number, which looks awful.)

How does one either reduce the chapter title font, or prevent longer titles from bumping onto the next page?

Any help would be much appreciated (I don't see the font settings for \chapter{...} anywhere)

Here's the template
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv

The Dissertate.cls is copied below (under the screenshots).

[image: short chapter titles look good]
[image: longer chapter titles cause this problem]

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  @LaTeX-class-file{
%     filename        = "Dissertate.cls",
%     version         = "1.0",
%     date            = "24 January 2014",
%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%     keywords        = "LaTeX, Dissertate",
%     supported       = "send email to suchow@post.harvard.edu",
%     docstring       = "Class for a dissertation."
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Dissertate}[2014/01/24 v1.0 Dissertate Class]
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}

% some definitions
\def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\def\degreemonth#1{\gdef\@degreemonth{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\field#1{\gdef\@field{#1}}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\universitycity#1{\gdef\@universitycity{#1}}
\def\universitystate#1{\gdef\@universitystate{#1}}
\def\programname#1{\gdef\@programname{#1}}
\def\pdOneName#1{\gdef\@pdOneName{#1}}
\def\pdOneSchool#1{\gdef\@pdOneSchool{#1}}
\def\pdOneYear#1{\gdef\@pdOneYear{#1}}
\def\pdTwoName#1{\gdef\@pdTwoName{#1}}
\def\pdTwoSchool#1{\gdef\@pdTwoSchool{#1}}
\def\pdTwoYear#1{\gdef\@pdTwoYear{#1}}

\RequirePackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[tiny, md, sc]{titlesec}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\RequirePackage{titling}
\RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption{School}[]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\RequirePackage{packages/\Dissertate@School/style}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{chapter}.A\arabic{section}}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage[tight,nice]{units}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\RequirePackage{url}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
% \usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Listing of figures}
\RaggedRight

\parindent 12pt
\RequirePackage{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional},SizeFeatures={{Size=-8, OpticalSize=8},{Size= 8-, OpticalSize=12}},]{EB Garamond}
\setmathrm{EB Garamond}

\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, BoldFont={Lato Bold}]{Lato Regular}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Mono} % Font substitution for Source Code Pro

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                                textfont={sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                                justification={justified,RaggedRight},
                                singlelinecheck=false,
                                margin=0pt,
                                figurewithin=chapter,
                                tablewithin=chapter]{caption}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

% an environment for paragraph-style section
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}%
}

% Align reference numbers so that they do not cause an indent
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{0pt}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{999}}
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}
     \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hi. Your .CLS loads the [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to adjust the headings (for some reason with `usepackage` instead of `RequirePackage`...). So you can easily edit the settings.

Comment: Hmm  It looks like  tocloft  is for the Table of Contents and   titlesec  is handling the chapter names/numbers -- am I incorrect?  I still don't see where the custom chapter title formatting is being set by the .cls file though

Comment: Right, a typo from, sorry.

Comment: I find the **cls** file is some kind of strange. Many packages are loaded using `usepackage` which is not recommended in such a file. Moreover, some options are loaded multiple times (`letterpaper`) and it uses different packages to change the layout of the headings. Plus, there is a not findable package loaded by an option that may also change some style issues: `\RequirePackage{packages/\Dissertate@School/style}`. If **I** don't had to, I wouldn't use that template. Its more or less an obscure conglomerate of many different packages of which some may interfere each other...

Comment: Thanks. I still can't seem to fix the problem. I can overwrite *all* chapter title settings by setting \titleformat{\chapter}, but I don't see how to modify just the font of the chapter titles (without changing the number & color). Where are these set?  Alternatively, I also don't see how to just move the chapter titles & numbers up to make more room for long titles.

Sadly, there's no good alternative to using this template (Harvard dissertations almost all use it because it meets a very long/odd series of official requirements)

Comment: I'm sorry, but since someone who wants to help, has to download the whole template, work through it, and maybe also the additional unknown package, I'm not sure you'll find someone who is willing (but maybe you're lucky ;) ). For me its too much effort. In general, take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390684/297560) why sometimes templates do you more harm than help

Comment: There is an email address in the cls file and a github link in the [tag information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/dissertate/info). So you should use one of them — best github — to report the issue.

Comment: EDIT: it's the quotchap package that's setting chapter number/title font and placement. The following (after quotchap) will adjust the font and placement of the chapter titles:

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4.0\baselineskip}} % move chapter number and title up towards top of page
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{5.3\baselineskip}}  %increase space between chapter title and chapter text
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{\@defaultcnfont}{b}{n}\fontsize{80}{110}\selectfont% Default: 100/130 so this setting shrinks the chapter number and title font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `quotchap` package that's setting chapter number/title font and placement. The following examples (after quotchap in the .cls) will adjust the font and placement of the chapter titles:

```
%move chapter number and title up towards top of page
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4.0\baselineskip}}

%increase space between chapter title and chapter text 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{5.3\baselineskip}} 

% Default: 100/130 so this setting shrinks the chapter number and title font 
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{% \usefont{T1}{\@defaultcnfont}{b}{n}\fontsize{80}{110}\selectfont
```